# Notification controls not working on OnePlus device in Kotlin music player app

Tags: android, kotlin

notification controls are not working like play pause and next prev
this is the code for creating notification it works on emulator with android 13 and 14 but not working on oneplus 9 pro with android 13 and also the cover image in notification is pixelated

```
fun showNotification(playPauseBtn: Int){

        val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        } else {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }

        val prevIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.PREVIOUS)
        val prevPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext,0,prevIntent, flag)

        val playIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.PLAY)
        val playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext,0,playIntent, flag)

        val nextIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.NEXT)
        val nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext,0,nextIntent, flag)

        val exitIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.EXIT)
        val exitPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext,0,exitIntent, flag)

        val imgArt = getImgArt(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].path)
        val image = if (imgArt != null){
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArt,0,imgArt.size)
        }else{
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.placeholder)
        }


        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext,ApplicationClass.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].title)
            .setContentText(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artist)
            .setSmallIcon(androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R.drawable.tooltip_frame_light)
            .setLargeIcon(image)
            .setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous,"Previous",prevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(playPauseBtn,"Play",playPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next,"Next",nextPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_exit_to_app_24,"Exit",exitPendingIntent)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
    }
```

here. is notification receiver code where  i handle actions like. play. pause next prev

```
class NotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when(intent?.action){
            ApplicationClass.PREVIOUS -> prevNextSong(increment = false, context = context!!)
            ApplicationClass.PLAY -> if (PlayerActivity.isPlaying) pauseMusic() else playMusic()
            ApplicationClass.NEXT -> prevNextSong(increment = true, context = context!!)
            ApplicationClass.EXIT ->{
                PlayerActivity.musicService!!.stopForeground(true)
                PlayerActivity.musicService = null
                exitProcess(1)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun playMusic(){
        PlayerActivity.isPlaying = true
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.start()
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.showNotification(R.drawable.ic_pause)
        PlayerActivity.binding.btnPlay.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_pause)
        NowPlaying.binding.btnPlayNP.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause)
    }

    private fun pauseMusic(){
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
            PlayerActivity.musicService,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        PlayerActivity.isPlaying = false
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.pause()
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.showNotification(R.drawable.ic_play)
        PlayerActivity.binding.btnPlay.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_play)
        NowPlaying.binding.btnPlayNP.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play)
    }
    private fun prevNextSong(increment : Boolean, context: Context){
        setSongPosition(increment = increment)
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.createMediaPlayer()
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).centerCrop())
            .into(PlayerActivity.binding.songCoverPA)
        PlayerActivity.binding.songNamePA.text = PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].title
        PlayerActivity.binding.descriptionPA.text = PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artist
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).centerCrop())
            .into(NowPlaying.binding.songCoverNP)
        NowPlaying.binding.songNameNP.text = PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].title
        playMusic()

        PlayerActivity.fIndex = favouriteChecker(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].id)
        if (PlayerActivity.isFavourite)PlayerActivity.binding.btnFavouritesPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.favourite_icon)
        else PlayerActivity.binding.btnFavouritesPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.favourite_empty_icon)

    }
}
```